# Do TVS diodes have polarity?

Tags: diodes, datasheet, layout, tvs

I am making a USB to UART circuit for ESP32.

Why does the [*LESD5D5.0CT1G* datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_LRC-LESD5D5.0CT1G_C383211.pdf) show a polarity marking? Aren't TVS bidirectional? What is the right position for such a diode?

[image]

My circuit:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TVS's](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Transient_voltage_suppressor) are power Zener diodes that operate with lower impedance than signal Zeners and lower voltage and more robust than MOV's.

Both TVS and MOV's come in uni- and bi-directional models.

Your datasheet shows the characteristics and answers your question. It is clearly bi-polar.

[image]

[image]

They seem to show that they use the same package case for both uni & bi-polar chips, so disregard this marking.

Comment: If you truncate  my link for the book , you will find the factory website of this TVS, you will be amazed at their diverse products and their interesting downloads. Also they have the Design Book by the infamous Bob Pease  https://www.jotrin.com/userfiles/downloadfile/202003121610523330.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tony! I will read that book, looks super interesting!

Answer (score 9):

No, TVS's are not bidirectional. You can buy bidirectional TVS's but these are just co-packaged unidirectional TVS's

However, it is normal that bidirectional TVS's include a polarity marking simply because of the common package used. In such situations the correct orientation is to align to the pin, ie Pin1 == Polarity marking side.

Comment: I see.. then in my case that is not bidirectional, what is the right position??

Answer (score 2):

The TVS diode you have is symmetrical, but not all TVS diodes are symmetrical.

The TVS is packaged in a standard package, and therefore it makes sense to mark which pin is which, as it makes more sense to define the pins than to explain to people why it does not have a marking to define pin 1 and it can be mounted in any direction.

Comment: +1 for "it avoids customer service calls", just like "WARNING: coffee is hot"